# Stuck Unconfirmed Transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

what I need to do about stuck transaction more than a week with 1 sat/vbyte ?[image]

Comment: If your wallet supports it and enabled it by default you can use RBF (Replace-By-Fee) to create a new version of the transaction that pays a higher feerate. What wallet did you use?

Comment: ord wallet, the stuck transactions are related to Inscription so would it be safe to follow your steps

Comment: ord wallet doesn't appear to provide users a method for fee-bumping, per: https://github.com/casey/ord/issues/1519.

Comment: How can I use createrawtransaction to create a new transaction that double spends same input with same output and amount?

Comment: @Soufiane you can use any of the normal `bitcoin-cli` commands, as the transaction is a regular bitcoin transaction. However, Bitcoin Core treats all sats as fungible and is unaware of any extra meaning you may have attached to them. By using `bitcoin-cli` directly, you accept the risk that "inscribed" sats in your wallet may be used to pay fees, etc

Comment: @josie I want to use createrawtransaction with only one input same as stuck transaction. It will pay the fees.

Comment: I deleted mempool.dat and did CPFP for stuck transaction after restarting core and it's worked, tx id: tx id: b7030b3abbb5e8873b3c8dd049f068211744c824b5b951f5ee65c23a7a0d0076

thanks to '/dev/fd0'